# Not able to add EmojiCompat library(com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0) to my app gradle

Tags: android, emoji

I a trying to use the EmojiCompat support library in my Android app. When i add -com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0 - as a dependency in app module gradle and try to sync it, i get below error -

```
Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0
```

Below is my build.gradle(project module)

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.script(app module) below -

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.example.com.emojis2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //adding lib

    compile 'com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0'
}
```

What am i missing , can someone please help ! Thanks in advance ...

Comment: @Gabriele - This is not a duplicate question. In the question , which you are referring to , the library is different than the one mentioned here.

Comment: The same answer is valid for all support libraries.

Comment: add *google()* like this in *PROJECT LEVEL GRADLE* like this 
`buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0

You should add this in your **PROJECT LEVEL**  `build.gradle` section .

```
 allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
    }
```

**DEMO**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         // You need to add the following repository to download the new plugin.
         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' 

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

**FYI**

To add them to your build, you need to first include **`Google's Maven repository`** in your top-level **`build.gradle`** file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , did not help. I have updated my question with app module and project module gradles. Thanks for your time. Could you please check.

Comment: @Paathak You added to the wrong repositories section

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - Yes ! Thanks , it worked... :) Tried letting you know through an upvote.  I am a newbie and have very less reputation on SO. So it says it has registered my feedback but cant increment the vote count . Thanks again :)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - Done ! Hey i just got some points added t my score so now i am able to upvote your answer. Guess it was because i clicked on tick sign ....

Comment: you can also solve it just add *google()* in `repositories {
        jcenter()
      google()
    }` in buildScript and allprojects.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel yes yes .

Comment: then update you ans, it look more pretty.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel add .Thanks for poking .You can edit this answer .